# Using static void Main() method from base class as a program's entry point

Tags: c#, console-application, entry-point

I would like to abstract some program logic to a base class for executing a command-line program (functionality similar to what [this question was requesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420606/base-class-to-handle-behavior-customize-features-etc-in-console-application)).

in other words, something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseProgram<T>
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
    }
}

public class Program : BaseProgram<string>
{
}
```

It is important to note that BaseProgram is in a different assembly.

This, however, does not work. The `static void Main(string[] args)` method *must* be in the derived class. Can anyone explain why that is? After all, the following is totally 'legal':

```
Program.Main(null);
BaseProgram<string>.Main(null);
```

and will output:

```
> System.String
> System.String
```

**What I would like to know**: are there any documented reasons for this outcome?

Comment: I would imagine because it cannot instantiate the implicit startup object. Did you try *explicitly* setting the startup object?

Comment: Use Program.Main() for entry point and instantiate your own class tree there.

Comment: Yes, @abatishchev, that's what I'm doing to achieve the functionality that I was after, but I wanted to know if there was a reason that it just didn't use the `Main` method in the base class.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET No, I did not. It doesn't allow me to set the base class as the startup object, however. Only the 'Program' class is available. Perhaps because it is in a different project?

Comment: Explicitly setting to `Program` *may* work.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET That did not work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was eventually disclosed during the commenting of the other answer, your `BaseProgram<T>` class is in a different assembly from the one you are trying to execute. The entry point of an assembly has to be in *that* assembly.

To do otherwise is like giving someone a key and telling them that's the key to your house's front door. Except the key is actually for some other completely different house's front door, so when they show up at your house it does them no good.

If you want to use the `BaseProgram<T>`'s `Main()` method, you need to delegate to it. For example, in your own assembly:

```
static class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        return BaseProgram<string>.Main(args);
    }
}
```

Note that for static types or static members of types, there's no need to actually inherit the base type, since you just invoke it via the actual type name instead of an instance reference.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that `BaseClass` is generic. In order to call main you have to supply a type argument, so which type should the system choose to call this method? Ofcourse it can't make random choices so this is illegal.

I found this in `C# 5.0 Language Specification` in `3.1 Application Startup`

> The application entry point method may not be in a generic class declaration.

Comment: I just removed the Generic parameter from the base class and it still will not compile (and I also cannot set it as the "startup object"). This would *definitely* make sense though...

Comment: That spec. totally backs up your answer. However, I'm still convinced this is a different issue.

When I make `Program` generic and `BaseProgram` non generic (a la `Program<T> : BaseProgram`) I receive a different compiler error: Error 14 'Program<T>' specified for Main method must be a valid class or struct Program.cs

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, with `Program : BaseProgram` I receive "'Program' does not have a suitable static Main method" (`Program` does not have `public static void Main(string[] args)` and `BaseProgram` does.

They are in separate projects, do you think that could be the reason?

Comment: ofcourse that could be the reason. each project should have a separate main method if the project type is not class library. Why didn't you say that you have two separate projects?

Comment: @skeryl: of course that's the reason. The entry point of an assembly has to be in that assembly! Had you mentioned that was the case, your question would have been correctly answered 19 minutes ago.

Comment: @Peter-Duniho It makes sense. But it also removes any use for the abstraction outside of this one Program class. The point of abstracting the logic to an external class library is so that I can re-use this code in several console applications in many solutions.

Comment: @skeryl: it doesn't "remove any use" of the abstraction. All it means is that you need to define a valid entry point in _your_ assembly. You can always delegate actual functionality to another assembly, including by inheriting a generic base class which you then call.

Comment: @Peter-Duniho What I meant was: If one were to create a base class to encapsulate program logic, and then include that base class inside of an assembly purely to defer the "entry point" to that base class, that would not make any sense. As stated in your answer, it makes way more sense to simply call the base class's method.